# KnpMenuBundle add icon/glyphicon

Tags: symfony, twig

I have tried to set an icon next to the link of the menu generated by `knpMenuBundle` but no way to get it.

I found some solutions like `->setAttribute` or `->setExtra`,  but I can't make it work.

Do I have to add specific lines to the base template of knp ?
Do something special in the twig render ?

Here is what I have tried so far:

//Builder.php

```
$public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
{
    $menu = $factory->createItem('root');
    $menu->setChildrenAttribute('class', 'nav navbar-nav ');

        $menu->addChild('Mes Informations',['route' => 'espace_client_mesInformations'])
            ->setAttribute('icon','fa fa-home');

        $menu->addChild('Mes Factures', array('route' => 'espace_client_mesFactures'));

        $menu->addChild('Mon Extrait de Compte', array('route' => 'espace_client_mesReglements'));

        $menu->addChild('Mes Services', array('route' => 'espace_client_mesServices'));

        $menu->addChild('Mes Consommations', array('route' => 'espace_client_mesConsommations'));

            $menu['Mes Consommations']->addChild('Télephone', array('route' => 'espace_client_mesConsoTelephone'));
            $menu['Mes Consommations']->addChild('Internet', array('route' => 'espace_client_mesConsoInternet'));

        $menu->addChild('Mes Liens Directs', array('route' => 'espace_client_mesLiens'));

    return $menu;
}
```

//menu.html.twig

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <center><h4> Menu </h4></center>
</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

    {{ knp_menu_render('EspaceClientBundle:Builder:mainMenu',{'currentAsLink':false, 'template': 'EspaceClientBundle:Menu:knp_menu.html.twig'}) }}

    </div>
```

If anyone have an answer ?
Thanks.

Edit:

I'm a little bit confused by the different files of the bundle, I must have a problem in my php code so there is the content of them:

`//knp_menu.html.twig`:

```
            {% extends 'knp_menu_base.html.twig' %}

        {% macro attributes(attributes) %}
        {% for name, value in attributes %}
            {%- if value is not none and value is not same as(false) -%}
                {{- ' %s="%s"'|format(name, value is same as(true) ? name|e : value|e)|raw -}}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
        {% endmacro %}

        {% block compressed_root %}
        {% spaceless %}
        {{ block('root') }}
        {% endspaceless %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block root %}
        {% set listAttributes = item.childrenAttributes %}
        {{ block('list') -}}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block list %}
        {% if item.hasChildren and options.depth is not same as(0) and item.displayChildren %}
            {% import _self as knp_menu %}
            <ul{{ knp_menu.attributes(listAttributes) }}>
                {{ block('children') }}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block children %}
        {# save current variables #}
        {% set currentOptions = options %}
        {% set currentItem = item %}
        {# update the depth for children #}
        {% if options.depth is not none %}
        {% set options = options|merge({'depth': currentOptions.depth - 1}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {# update the matchingDepth for children #}
        {% if options.matchingDepth is not none and options.matchingDepth > 0 %}
        {% set options = options|merge({'matchingDepth': currentOptions.matchingDepth - 1}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% for item in currentItem.children %}
            {{ block('item') }}
        {% endfor %}
        {# restore current variables #}
        {% set item = currentItem %}
        {% set options = currentOptions %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block item %}
        {% if item.displayed %}
        {# building the class of the item #}
            {%- set classes = item.attribute('class') is not empty ? [item.attribute('class')] : [] %}
            {%- if matcher.isCurrent(item) %}
                {%- set classes = classes|merge([options.currentClass]) %}
            {%- elseif matcher.isAncestor(item, options.matchingDepth) %}
                {%- set classes = classes|merge([options.ancestorClass]) %}
            {%- endif %}
            {%- if item.actsLikeFirst %}
                {%- set classes = classes|merge([options.firstClass]) %}
            {%- endif %}
            {%- if item.actsLikeLast %}
                {%- set classes = classes|merge([options.lastClass]) %}
            {%- endif %}

            {# Mark item as "leaf" (no children) or as "branch" (has children that are displayed) #}
            {% if item.hasChildren and options.depth is not same as(0) %}
                {% if options.branch_class is not empty and item.displayChildren %}
                    {%- set classes = classes|merge([options.branch_class]) %}
                {% endif %}
            {% elseif options.leaf_class is not empty %}
                {%- set classes = classes|merge([options.leaf_class]) %}
            {%- endif %}

            {%- set attributes = item.attributes %}
            {%- if classes is not empty %}
                {%- set attributes = attributes|merge({'class': classes|join(' ')}) %}
            {%- endif %}
        {# displaying the item #}
            {% import _self as knp_menu %}
            <li{{ knp_menu.attributes(attributes) }}>
                {%- if item.uri is not empty and (not matcher.isCurrent(item) or options.currentAsLink) %}
                {{ block('linkElement') }}
                {%- else %}
                {{ block('spanElement') }}
                {%- endif %}
        {# render the list of children#}
                {%- set childrenClasses = item.childrenAttribute('class') is not empty ? [item.childrenAttribute('class')] : [] %}
                {%- set childrenClasses = childrenClasses|merge(['menu_level_' ~ item.level]) %}
                {%- set listAttributes = item.childrenAttributes|merge({'class': childrenClasses|join(' ') }) %}
                {{ block('list') }}
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block linkElement %}
            {% import "knp_menu.html.twig" as macros %}
            <a href="{{ item.uri }}"{{ macros.attributes(item.linkAttributes) }}>
                <span class="icon">{{ item.getExtra('icon') }}</span>
                <span class="entry">{{ block('label') }}</span>
            </a>
        {% endblock %}

        {% block spanElement %}{% import _self as knp_menu %}<span{{ knp_menu.attributes(item.labelAttributes) }}>{{ block('label') }}</span>{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your menu template `EspaceClientBundle:Menu:knp_menu.html.twig` like:

```
{% block label %}
    {% if options.allow_safe_labels and item.getExtra('safe_label', false) %}
        {{ item.label|raw|trans }}
    {% else %}
        {{ item.label }}
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.extras.icon is defined %}
        <i class="{{ item.extras.icon }}"></i>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I recommend you, to delete the whitespaces between twig tags.

Then, in menu builder:

```
$menu->addChild('Mes Informations', [
    'route' => 'espace_client_mesInformations',
    'extras' => ['icon' => 'fa fa-home']
]);
```

Comment: thanks you for reply ! I'have tried but still not working, I don't understand.

Comment: Maybe, your knpmenubundle version is different, so try to use `{{ item.getExtra('icon') }}` instead of `{{ item.extras.icon }}`

Comment: Also, try to dump your menu item in twig template, so you can see all the array childs `{{ dump(item) }}`

Comment: I'have tried it but style not working, I'have also tried to dump item and i get  an array extras with the `fa fa-home` and actually I just get this before the name of the child as "fa fa-home Mes Informations" in my rendered menu.

Comment: It means, that php code is working correctly. You should look for problems in your css. Do you included font-awesome lib in your html? does your browser load all font-awesome fonts? Web developer toolbar in browser will help you. Also look in network tab, are there any problems with loading assets

Comment: Now I get the same result but the icon appears after the link and I'm still having the full text fa fa-home. Idea ?

Comment: `{% block label %}
    {% if item.extras.icon is defined %}
        <i class="{{ item.extras.icon }}"></i>
    {% endif %}
    {% if options.allow_safe_labels and item.getExtra('safe_label', false) %}
        {{ item.label|raw }}
    {% else %}
        {{ item.label }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}`